# Why is my pygame ball not accelerating when using classes?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

so I am new to pygame/python/coding and first time using classes. I already made a working pygame program of a ball bouncing around and accelerating with gravity. However, now that I use classes, the ball only seems to be moving at a constant speed. Please tell me what I am doing wrong and how 
I should change my code. Thanks in advance!

```
import pygame, sys


pygame.init()

red = (255,0,0)
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
blue = (0,0,255)

pygame.mouse.set_visible(0)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

displaySize = (800,600)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(displaySize)

g = 30
dt = 0.05

class ball:
    def __init__(self, x, y, vx, vy, r,ax,ay, color):

        dt = 0.05

        Cd = 0.01
        m = 5

        self.ay = ay
        self.ax = ax

        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.r = r
        self.color = color

        self.vx = vx
        self.vy = vx

def update(self, x, y):


    x, y = physics()
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.color, (int(round(x)),int(round(y))), self.r)
    pygame.display.update()

    def physics(self):


        self.Dy = Cd*self.vy*abs(self.vy)
        self.Dx = Cd*self.vx*abs(self.vx)

        self.Fy = self.m*g - self.Dy
        self.Fx = -self.Dx

        self.ay = self.Fy/m
        self.ax = self.Fx/m

        self.vy += self.ay*dt
        self.vx += self.ax*dt

        self.x +=self.vx*dt
        self.y +=self.vy*dt

        return self.x, self.y

one = ball(100,100,0,0,0,0,30,red)

while 1:
    clock.tick(30)
    screen.fill(blue)
    one.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

Comment: Where is the acceleration code? You should reduce this down to a [mcve]. Half the code here seems to be irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

self.vx and self.vy should be within the constructor method instead of the physics method, otherwise their values will be set back to 50 and 0 each time the physics method is called within the game loop, resulting in a constant speed.

Comment: Okay, I understand what you mean. just adding self.vx and self.vy to the constructor didnt solve the problem, so I tried adding more things to it. I changed the code above into what I now think it should be like. Do you see any way to make it work now?